Decomposing Gaussian measure as a product and its effect on integration
Let $\gamma^A$ be the Gaussian measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with covariance $A$. Thus in terms of the Lebesgue measure $dx$ we have:
$$d\gamma^A = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}|A|^{1/2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\langle x, A^{-1}x\rangle} dx.$$
Since $A$ is a matrix, we may decompose $A$ and $A = B + C$ for some matrices $B$ and $C$.
Is it possible to relate the integral of a function against $d\gamma^A$ and the iterated integrals $d\gamma^B d\gamma^C$? That is, is it true that for any integrable function $f$
$$\int f(x)\gamma^A(dx) = \int\Bigg(\int f(y, z) d\gamma^B(y)\Bigg) d\gamma^C(z) = \int\Bigg(\int f(y, z) d\gamma^C(z)\Bigg) d\gamma^B(y)?$$
I think this requires the Gaussian distributions defined by $\gamma^B$ and $\gamma^C$ to be independent, but under what conditions is this true?
